# How to add class to the last image of the last post in a loop [Wordpress]

Tags: jquery, wordpress

ok, I'm creating a portfolio page, I want add a class to my last portfolio thumbnail. currently I have a class added to the div of the last portfolio item. I want to add it to the thumbnail, not the div itself.

my code:

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'order' => 'ASC');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<div class="testing_imran<?php echo $loop->current_post + 1 === $loop->post_count ? ' imd_last' : '' ?>">
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'main-image portfolio' ) ); ?>
</div>           
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I want that "imd_last" class added to the post-thumbnail not the div. how can I do it? by the way, the thumbnails have a class attached as you can see, I just want to add an extra class to the last thumbnail. 
[image]

Comment: is your above code adding this class "imd_last" to last thumbnail div??

Comment: yes, it does. & I want this class  to added to the thumbnail, not the div. screenshot attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'order' => 'ASC');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php $extraLastClass = $loop->current_post + 1 === $loop->post_count ? ' imd_last' : '';?>
<div class="testing_imran">
<?php the_post_thumbnail( "thumbnail", array( "class" => "main-image portfolio $extraLastClass" ) ); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Wow, so simple with variable. great work & thank you very much.

Comment: its my pleasure @Aohor Arsalan

Answer (score 0):

If u want do it, u can use CSS :last-child
or use Jquery and add dynamically last class as `$("div").last().addClacss("myclass");`